# Restrict interface type parameter to class that is implementing the interface

Tags: c#, interface, restriction, type-parameter

I'd like to create an interface that gives objects of certain classes an id and a dictionary where you can find the reference by Id. So every class should have their own counting id (starting at 1).

That is what I have:

```
interface IIdentifiable<T>
{
    public int id { get; }
    public static int NextId { get; private set; } = 1;
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, T> InstanceById = new Dictionary<int, T>();


    public static T GetInstanceById(int id)
    {
        return InstanceById[id];
    }

    protected static void AddInstanceById(T instance, int id)
    {
        InstanceById.Add(id, instance);
    }
    
    protected static void IncrementNextId() => NextId++;
}
```

It works, but I'd like to restrict it in the way so that every class is only allowed to implement the interface that corresponds to the class.

e.g.:

```
class A : IIdentifiable<A> // how to make sure, that only A is allowed here?
{ }
```

I know about type restrictions, but they don't suit for this case because they are defined in the interface via (where T : ..) but the interface can't know what class it is currently implemented by.

Is there any way to formulate this restriction? Maybe also using a slightly different architechture?

Thanks!

Comment: "to make sure, that only A is allowed here" - why generic then?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy _"why generic then?"_ OP means "`A` should only be allowed to implement `IIdentifyable<A>` and not for example `IIdentifyable<B>`"

Comment: This sort of thing is what Eiffel calls an "anchored" type. C# has no support for something like this. This is not usually a problem either: clients who choose to shoot themselves in the foot by supplying a different type will very quickly find that it doesn't work. Think about it -- when's the last time you failed to implement `IEquatable` correctly by supplying a type parameter other than the class itself? About the only way this could happen is if you're copy-pasting code and failing to adjust it, which should be uncommon anyway.

Comment: An alternative is to make classes implement a non-generic interface (or base type, since there's not much point to making every class re-implement it) that only contains `Id`, and have a separate factory type for getting/creating instances rather than making it part of the class itself, the latter of which can be generic and would take any `T` implementing `IIdentifiable`.

Comment: @Fildor thank you for making that clear.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you're right that it's more about protecting the programmer from shooting himself in the foot. But I was curious if its possible to make it foolproof.